# How should I achieve dynamic generate Form::date() in laravel 8

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, laravel-8

How should I achieve dynamic generate `Form::date()`, when I select `1`, generate `Form::date()` under the `Form::select()`, when I select `0` hide `Form::date()` in the this view.

Example:

option :

[image]

select 0 :

[image]

select 1 :

[image]

Comment: Embed your images into the question

Answer (score 0):

try to use javascript to hide or show the input: date.

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;

  if (x == '1')
  {
     document.getElementById('date').style.display = 'inline-block';
  }
  else  if (x == '0') {
      document.getElementById('date').style.display = 'none';
  }
  
}
```